# How to replace images in blender file?

Tags: texturing, materials, image, blend-files

I downloaded a model from someone but noticed the textures take up way too much space. Is there a way I can replace this images with lower quality images without having to replace them in the shaders?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose all the textures you're talking about are packed? What you could do is go in the *File* menu > *External Data > Unpack All Into Files* which will create a texture folder next to your file, replace all the high-quality images with low-quality, keeping the exact same name, then *File* menu > *External Data > Pack All Into .blend*.

Answer (score 1):

From the image editor, you can resize them:

[image]

If they are not packed in the blend file, save them after that.

Comment: I didn't know that, too bad there is no "constrain proportions" option

Comment: @moonboots, yes I agree.